# Why is segmentation fault coming in kernel ?

Tags: c, operating-system, segmentation-fault, kernel

I am learning os kernel development and still at a very beginner level. I have written a bit of code for 80386 processor and testing it on qemu using gdb as a debugger (remote debugging).

Now, strange error is coming  :- When , I run the code in qemu, it runs fine but when I run it and connect it to gdb. gdb shows segmentation fault in it at a line.

My, question is that how can segmentation fault come in the os kernel when I am running in real mode currently and haven't even used memory protection. Also, if there is a mechanism by which segmentation fault is generated why is the kernel running fine in qemu.

Answer (score 0):

The seg fault is thrown by the hardware not the OS. So yes you can still get segfaults, but segfaults are some of the easier bugs to fix.

Comment: Can hardware throw seg faults in real mode also? Isn't it to be implemented by the kernel.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is, but I built an OS in college and had to debug several segfaults in my code even though I never wrote any code to protect memory.

Comment: One more thing related to this is that in the Intel manual 80386 it's written that whenever exception occurs it saves the contents of cs and eip registers. Any idea how to access those saved registers ?

Comment: This should be in your trap frame. The trap frame is where you save all your registers during context switching.